# How to know if $interpolate fails in AngularJS 1.2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the `$interpolate` service in AngularJS 1.2.16.  However, I don't know how to check if Angular has properly interpolated all the vars in my string or not.

I noticed in AngularJS 1.3 they have added a new parameter `AllOrNothing`, which will cause the interpolate function to return an undefined if any embedded expressions fail to evaluate fully.

Any ideas how I can perform a similar check in 1.2?  I would be okay looking for any embedded expressions, but Angular will strip them from the string if they are not specified in the context, so I can't even look for non-evaluated tokens in the returned string.

Comment: After looking at the source code, I don't think this is possible in 1.2.x. See [interpolate.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.20/src/ng/interpolate.js#L181)

Comment: @runTarm  Thanks; that's kind of what I figured too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a unit test:

```
var exp = $interpolate('Hello {{name | uppercase}}!');
expect(exp({name:'Angular'}).toEqual('Hello ANGULAR!');
```

**References**

- [AngularJS Source: interpolateSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/interpolateSpec.js)